# Connection timed out exception in java HttpClient library but not through chrome browser?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have blocked a port 8070 by the following command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 8070 -j DROP
```

Now, when I deploy my web application in embedded Tomcat 7 on port 8070, and If I access through the URL `http://localhost:8070/app` or `http://192.168.1.3:8070/app`, I always get the exception `Connection timed out`. That is usual because I have blocked that port.

But when I access the URL `http://192.168.1.3:8070/app` through the chrome browser, I get the `Connection Timed out` error message. That is also as expected. **But When I try to access `http://localhost:8070/app` through chrome browser, It gives me successful response.** This is unusual.

Why I am able to access through browser on localhost, but not through Apache HttpClient library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome uses IPv6 so it can resolve localhost using that, the other examples are using IPv4. So check your hosts file if it contains an `::1` entry for localhost?

You can try with no IPv6 for chrome as well with this command line flag:

`--disable-ipv6`

Comment: Hi Pulsar, Thanks for replying, I have tried the approach `--disable-ipv6` but I am still able to access `http://localhost:8070/app`. I think you have misinterpreted my question. What will IPv6 will do in this case, I have blocked that port and I am still able to access it through browser, but not from JAVA code.

Comment: No I don't think I misunderstood, though it was a theory as I'm unable to test your setup :) The java code might only use IPv4 (depending on the exact call they are using in that library along with jvm version and OS + os version). But try and check what `ip6tables -v -nL | grep DROP` says perhaps? Sorry haven't fiddled with iptables in a while.

Comment: Hi Pulsar, I have tried first approach (commenting the ::1 entry), and now it stopped responding to http://localhost:8070/app as well. It is working, But I am still confused, What is going on?

Comment: Have to check the iptables doc, can't remember the IPv4 vs IPv6 stuff  I'm afraid. Maybe you are just dropping ipv4 traffic using your command, there is the `ip6tables` command as well for a reason I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Note, that this should be on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com).

But you should try indicating your network interface for `iptables` like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.1.3 --destination-port 8070 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --destination-port 8070 -j DROP
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow platform. From now on I will use http://serverfault.com for server related issues. I have executed both commands, but still I am able to access through `localhost`, although it is blocking on `127.0.0.1`. I have executed the command `iptables -v -nL | grep DROP` but found no entry for localhost.